# WiFi RSSI not updating when screen is off android device

Tags: android, android-wifi, rssi, sleep-mode

I have an application where,I need to get the updated WiFi RSSI when my device screen is OFF. I have already tried with different approaches found in stackoverflow. But no solution works for me till now.

1. Using the flag:

   WIFI_MODE_FULL_HIGH_PERF
2. Also tried using below policy:

   Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
     Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY, 
     Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER);

Is there any other way for getting the RSSI or am I missing something? My device OS is Marshmallow.

Comment: use wake locks to keep wifi radio (and other system components) active after phone goes to sleep.  nothing will stay active without a wake lock.

Comment: @escape-llc Already using Wake lock. Still not working

Comment: without any code hard to know if you did it correctly....

Comment: @Md.AliHossain Did you manage to find any solution? I have faced the same issue. Please let me know if you know any workaround it.